# How can I package or install an entire program to run in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, scrapy, aws-lambda

If this is a case of using Lambda entirely the wrong way, please let me know.

I want to install [Scrapy](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) into a Lambda function and invoke the function to begin a crawl.  My first problem is how to install it, so that all of the paths are correct.  I installed the program using the directory to be zipped as its root, so the zip contains all of the source files and the executable.  I am basing my efforts on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) article.  In the line it says to include at the beginning of my function, where does the "process" variable come from?  I have tried,

```
var process = require('child_process');
var exec = process.exec;
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + 
process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']
```

but I get the error,

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'PATH' of undefined",
"errorType": "TypeError",
```

Do I need to include all of the library files, or just the executable from /usr/lib ?  How do I include that one line of code the article says I need?

Edit:
I tried moving the code into a child_process.exec, and received the error

```
"errorMessage": "Command failed: /bin/sh: process.env[PATH]: command not found\n/bin/sh: scrapy: command not found\n"
```

Here is my current, entire function

```
console.log("STARTING");
var process = require('child_process');
var exec = process.exec;

exports.handler = function(event, context) {    
    //Run a fixed Python command.
    exec("process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']; scrapy crawl backpage2", function(error, stdout) {
        console.log('Scrapy returned: ' + stdout + '.');
        context.done(error, stdout);
    });

};
```

Comment: There is an example of how to "Running R Statistics in AWS Lambda" with all the steps: http://nafiux.com/blog/2015/09/11/running-r-statistics-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: @michaelAdam were you able to solve this problem? I am having exact same issue

Comment: HI @michaelAdam, it looks like [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40259180/39396) is correct; have you considered accepting one of the answers to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can definitely execute arbitrary processes from your Node code in Lambda. We're doing this to run a game server that processes player turns, for example. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish with Scrapy, but remember that your entire Lambda invocation can only live for a maximum of 60 seconds right now on AWS! But if that's OK for you, here is a completely working example of how we are executing our own arbitrary linux process from Lambda. (In our case, it's a compiled binary - really doesn't matter as long as you have something that can run on the Linux image they use).

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var path = require('path');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    // If timeout is provided in context, get it. Otherwise, assume 60 seconds
    var timeout = (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis && (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() - 1000)) || 60000;
    // The task root is the directory with the code package.
    var taskRoot = process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] || __dirname;
    // The command to execute.
    var command;

    // Set up environment variables
    process.env.HOME = '/tmp'; // <-- for naive processes that assume $HOME always works! You might not need this.

    // On linux the executable is in task root / __dirname, whichever was defined
    process.env.PATH += ':' + taskRoot;
    command = 'bash -c "cp -R /var/task/YOUR_THING /tmp/; cd /tmp; ./YOUR_THING ARG1 ARG2 ETC"'

    child_process.exec(command, {
        timeout: timeout,
        env: process.env
    }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        context.done(null, {exit: true, stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});
    });
};
```

Comment: We do all of that copying to /tmp and such because the process we're running expects its own location to be writable - but you get the idea.

Comment: Now, the max amount of time that a lambda can be alive is 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Problem with your example is modifying [node global variable](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_process) `process` by

`var process = require('child_process');`

This way you can't alter PATH environment variable, and thus the reason why you are getting `Cannot read property 'PATH' of undefined`.

Just use different name for loaded `child_process` library, e.g.

```
//this gets updated to child_process
var child_process = require('child_process');
var exec = child_process.exec;

//global process variable is still accessible
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + 
process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']

//start new process with your binary
exec('path/to/your/binary',......
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Lambda function that runs a python script setting the current working directory to the same directory as the Lambda function.  You may be able to use this with some modifications to the relative location of your python script.

```
var child_process = require("child_process");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var execOptions = {
        cwd: __dirname
    };
    child_process.exec("python hello.py", execOptions, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            context.fail(error);
        } else {
            console.log("stdout:\n", stdout);
            console.log("stderr:\n", stderr);
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I can run a single python script easily by just placing it next to the lamda function in the zipped directory. I'm wondering if it's possible to include an entire python (or any other language for that matter) library in the zip in such a way that the lambda can use it.